# "Spring Boot Application Started Successfully, but Getting JMX Service URL Retrieval Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application that appears to start successfully, but I'm encountering a notification about a JMX service URL retrieval error. Despite this notification, the application seems to run without any apparent issues.

Failed to retrieve application JMX service URL

```
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-11-21T11:22:53.545+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.13.Final
2023-11-21T11:22:53.547+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
2023-11-21T11:22:53.748+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2023-11-21T11:22:53.769+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-11-21T11:22:53.880+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@1d77746b
2023-11-21T11:22:53.882+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-11-21T11:22:53.915+05:30  WARN 8960 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: MySQLDialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2023-11-21T11:22:54.143+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2023-11-21T11:22:54.146+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-11-21T11:22:54.208+05:30  WARN 8960 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2023-11-21T11:22:54.506+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-11-21T11:22:54.512+05:30  INFO 8960 --- [           main] com.example.groups.GroupsApplication     : Started GroupsApplication in 2.466 seconds (process running for 3.059)
```

Configuration Files:

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

user.java class:

```
package entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="user")
public class user {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID",nullable = false,unique = true)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "Email",nullable = false)
    private String mailid;
    @Column(name = "Full Name",nullable = false)
    private String fullname;
    @Column(name = "Password",nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public user(long id, String mailid, String fullname, String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.mailid = mailid;
        this.fullname = fullname;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public user() {

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMailid() {
        return mailid;
    }

    public void setMailid(String mailid) {
        this.mailid = mailid;
    }

    public String getFullname() {
        return fullname;
    }

    public void setFullname(String fullname) {
        this.fullname = fullname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: There is no error just info and warning informing you on what is being configured.

Comment: but the table is not created in database

Comment: THat has nothing to do with JMX and if the table doesn't get created then why did you state *he application seems to run without any apparent issues*? Also your logging doesn't show anything JMX related.